# XPath with namespace as Predicate in SOAP Request

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I am working on SOAP client where I need to send the request which includes the XPATH as Predicates.
 Predicates involves in this case includes multi nodes and those element comes from different name spaces.

I want to generate the XPath so it knows about name space of its element. I have currently hard coded the name of the element along with the assumed namespace, as its being generated dynamically while creating the request. One thing I can fix the package-java.info with all the name spaces and configure plugin below to not generate these packages classes at all and hard code the name space while building the predicate. Some how I am not very much comfortable with this approach and think there should be a better approach.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <args>
                   <arg>-npa</arg>
                  </args>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Required request to be sent to the Webservice server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<exchange:SCNMessage xmlns:exchange="http://example1.com/abc/exchange" xmlns:scn="http://example1.com/abc/scn"
                         xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/abc/structure/2.0" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com/abc/core/2.0"
                         xmlns:ns5="http://example.com/abc/domains/migration/2.1"
                         xmlns:ns6="http://example.com/abc/domains/screening/2.1">
    <scn:SchemaVersion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <scn:Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <scn:Query>
        <scn:StartingResults>1</scn:StartingResults>
        <scn:MaximumResults>10</scn:MaximumResults>
        <scn:AsOfDateTime xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <scn:PredicateSet>
            <scn:PredicateSetIdentifier>Request Application Data</scn:PredicateSetIdentifier>
            <scn:Predicate>//scn:SCN/scn:ScnMetadata/scn:ReceivedSystem!=HELLO
            </scn:Predicate>
            <scn:Predicate>//scn:SCN/scn:Request/ns5:ActivityStatus/ns5:StatusText="KUAUN"</scn:Predicate>
            <scn:Predicate>//scn:SCN/scn:Request/ns6:Program="XYZ"</scn:Predicate>
            <scn:Predicate>//scn:SCN/scn:Request/scn:Source="ABC"</scn:Predicate>
            <scn:Predicate>//scn:SCN/ns3:Person/ns3:PersonCitizenshipCode="INR"</scn:Predicate>
        </scn:PredicateSet>
        <scn:ResultSet>
            <scn:ResultText>//scn:SCN/scn:Request</scn:ResultText>
        </scn:ResultSet>
    </scn:Query>
</exchange:SCNMessage>
```

Please let me know, if any one has solved a similar issue or any direction towards an elegant solution.